# Android button while swapping multiple values with multiple buttons

Tags: android, button

basically i am new to android programming and i am learning it and fun also.
I am trying to build an rummy like game using words and cards will be simulated as buttons.
Here i am facing a problem while swapping values between buttons.

Here is the simulation for my game,

```
[A][C][P] [W][D][G]

     [K][Z][I]

  [empty button]
```

If i click A button the value of A button should replace with empty button that is empty string.Now A is in empty button and A button should show empty string.

My application throws error as "unfortunately stopped working" in this switch statement as,

```
public class Play extends Activity
{   
int lastCard = RandomAlphabetGenerator.numOfCards; //52
int pos = lastCard;
int OpenCard0 = RandomAlphabetGenerator.OpenCard;  //27
int OpenCard1 = OpenCard0 + 1;

char[] stringarray = null;
char temp;

final Context context = this;

Button button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,buttonM,buttonFREE;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.play);

RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks = RandomAlphabetGenerator.Random();

stringarray = RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.toCharArray();

addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() 
{        
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
buttonM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showButton);
buttonFREE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emptyButton);

button1.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(0,1)); 
button2.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(1,2)); 
button3.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(2,3));
button4.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(3,4)); 
button5.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(4,5)); 
button6.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(5,6)); 
button7.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(6,7)); 
button8.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(7,8));
button9.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(8,9));      

buttonM.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(OpenCard0,OpenCard1));  

buttonFREE.setText("");

View.OnClickListener handler = new OnClickListener() 
{           
public void onClick(View v)
{ 
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.Button1:
button1.setText("");
process(0);
break;
case R.id.Button2:
button2.setText("");
process(1);
break;
case R.id.Button3:
button3.setText("");
process(2);
break;
case R.id.Button4:
button4.setText("");
process(3);
break;
case R.id.Button5:
button5.setText("");
process(4);
break;
case R.id.Button6:
button6.setText("");
process(5);
break;
case R.id.Button7:
button7.setText("");
process(6);
break;
case R.id.Button8:
button8.setText("");
process(7);
break;
case R.id.Button9:
button9.setText("");
process(8);
break;
case R.id.showButton:
buttonM.setText("");
process(OpenCard0);
break;
case R.id.emptyButton:
buttonFREE.setText("");
process(lastCard);
break;          
}       
RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks = new String(stringarray);
}

private void process(int k) 
{                
int j=k+1;

if(pos==OpenCard0)
{           
buttonM.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j));
}
else if(pos == lastCard)
{                  
buttonFREE.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j));   
}           
else 
{
switch(pos)
{
case 0: button1.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 1: button2.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 2: button3.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 3: button4.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 4: button5.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 5: button6.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 6: button7.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 7: button8.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
case 8: button9.setText(RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.substring(k,j)); break;
}
}

temp = stringarray[k];    
stringarray[k] = stringarray[pos];  //Program stops here  
stringarray[pos] = temp;  
pos = k; 
}
};
findViewById(R.id.Button1).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button2).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button3).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button4).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button5).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button6).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button7).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button8).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.Button9).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.emptyButton).setOnClickListener(handler);
findViewById(R.id.showButton).setOnClickListener(handler);
}   
}
```

Here is what logcat shows:

```
01-03 17:57:59.761: D/AndroidRuntime(705): Shutting down VM
01-03 17:57:59.761: W/dalvikvm(705): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=52; index=52
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705): at apk.games.wordrummy.Play$1.process(Play.java:158)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at apk.games.wordrummy.Play$1.onClick(Play.java:83)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-03 17:57:59.881: E/AndroidRuntime(705):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=52; index=52
Array is causing this

Comment: `stringarray = RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.toCharArray();` Does this generate an array that contains at least 53 elements?

Comment: No. M variable are no_of_Decks = 2; no_of_Cards = no_of_Decks * 26; So stringarray will store 0 to 51 from RandomAlphabetGenerator.shuffledDecks.toCharArray().